# ABBYY .lsa dictionaries not loaded in Goldendict

Tags: linux, fedora

I recently have found that only [goldendict](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/goldendict/) is modern QT application to integrate many dictionaries in a common platform, am using it under Fedora. After having installed it under Fedora I made it to scan a folder where I have many ABBYY dictionaries in .lsd format & audio modules in .lsa format. It scanned successfully & added all the audio files & do also gave me offline audio pronounciation however it failes to integrate any .lsd dictionaries.

In my android which also uses goldendict it auto scans & integrates .lsd files too but why not in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the LSD format is a closed proprietary format by Abbyy, and as such it is not supported in the PC version of GoldenDict, since GoldenDict is open source and the author decided not to put the code that deals with LSD dictionaries under open source license.

On Android, where the App is closed source, the handling of LSD dictionaries is enabled.